Which VS Code extension contributes the "Compile Active File" button for C and C++ in the editor title menu?
Which Visual Studio Code extension brings "Compile Active File" button that builds C++ code.

My Visual Studio Code has the C/C++, Makefile Tools, and CMake Tools extensions. But not all C++ projects have this button.

It's contributed by CMake Tools. Some related source code is here (you can navigate based on that and find the .nls.json file(s) and the .ts file that implements the command, and the place where it's registered to the editor title action bar menu (its when-clauses are resourceLangId == cpp && cmake:enableFullFeatureSet and/or resourceLangId == c && cmake:enableFullFeatureSet)).
As for why you don't see it in other projects, maybe you didn't enable the CMake Tools extension in that workspace, or the when-clauses for the editor title contribution didn't match, or the when-clauses for the command itself didn't match (cmake:enableFullFeatureSet).

How to activate CMake? I thought it activates automatically when it finds CMakeLists.txt
